# How to insert an IP-address into an inet column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, insert, psql

I would like to insert an IP-address into a column that has type `inet`. In what format can I insert the data? is it only binary or is there any way I can insert from text e.g. `"192.168.1.082"`? Are there any help-functions for this so I can test it from `psql` in the command prompt?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems pretty easy:

```
postgres=# create table inet_test (address inet);

CREATE TABLE

postgres=# insert into inet_test values ('192.168.2.1');

INSERT 0 1

postgres=# insert into inet_test values ('192.168.2.1/24');

INSERT 0 1

postgres=# select * from inet_test;


 address
----------------
 192.168.2.1
 192.168.2.1/24
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I only tried with `"192.168.1.082"`.

Comment: Cast your text value to `::INET`.  `'192.168.1.083'::INET` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you placing any STRINGS in POSTGRES with SINGLE QUOTES.

If you use DOUBLE QUOTES you will get errors, and this is a very common mistake.